# Hiding the directory path in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I hide the directory path in a batch file so that when I launch the .bat, I only see me pinging a computer without the directory path part.

Output Example:
    Ping 192.168.1.5

instead of: 
C:\Users\Joe\Desktop>Ping 192.168.1.5

Comment: I reversed your edit. You can't change the entire question to include new requirements after you've received answers to it. It changes the question, and can make the answers incomplete (or even wrong), and that's not fair to the people that posted the answers. If you now have a different question, post a separate question and ask it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@echo off` before the line that executes the ping command.

Or, if that's not possible for some reason, you can use an `@` sign in front of the command itself:

```
@ping 192,168.1.5
```

Comment: That totally worked, but it puts the pinging line and the reply line the same line. Is there anyway to new line it (\n) it somehow? It looks like updated code above

Comment: That's not the *pinging command*. That's part of the output of *ping* itself (the *reply*). Run `ping` yourself from a command prompt (window) and you'll see. You can hide *all of the output*, but that's not the question you asked here. :-) You asked about hiding the *directory part*, and that's what my answer does.

Comment: I understand it's not the command, but I'm guessing I'll have to format it somehow using java since my output is going into a textArea inside a GUI. Unless there's a way to format it within a batch script?

Comment: There's not. However, that's a totally different question. See my comment to your post above.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
Ping 192.168.1.5
pause
```